# How can I recreate the folder layout from Telegram in SwiftUI?

Tags: layout, swiftui, telegram, toolbar, spacing

I would like to recreate [this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUXQN.jpg), which is the layout of the Chat section from the Telegram app. The only thing I don't need to add is the horizontal scrolling. [This is what I was able to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi4Y5.jpg) for now, but there's still too much space between the navigation bar and the folders list. How do I reduce it to be as small as the one in the Telegram app?

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showMainView = true
    @State var showFirstView = false
    @State var showSecondView = false
    
    var allItems = ["Italy", "Germany", "France", "Ireland", "Austria", "Sweden", "Norway", "Russia", "Ukraine", "Spain", "Portugal"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                topMenu
                Form {
                    if showMainView {
                        ForEach(allItems, id: \.self) { itms in
                            Text(itms)
                        }
                    }
                    if showFirstView {
                        ForEach(allItems.filter({ $0.first == "F" || $0.first == "G" }), id: \.self) { itms in
                            Text(itms)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    if showSecondView {
                        Text("This folder is still empty!")
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("My List")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.leading)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: showMainView == true ? editButton : nil)
        }
    }
    
    var topMenu : some View {
        HStack(spacing: 15) {
            Button {
                showMainView = true
                showFirstView = false
                showSecondView = false
            } label: {
                if showMainView {
                    Text("All")
                        .underline()
                } else {
                    Text("All")
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            .foregroundColor(showMainView == true ? .green : .black)
            Button {
                showMainView = false
                showFirstView = true
                showSecondView = false
            } label: {
                if showFirstView {
                    Text("Folder 1")
                        .underline()
                } else {
                    Text("Folder 1")
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            .foregroundColor(showFirstView == true ? .green : .black)
            
            Button {
                showMainView = false
                showFirstView = false
                showSecondView = true
            } label: {
                if showSecondView {
                    Text("Folder 2")
                        .underline()
                } else {
                    Text("Folder 2")
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            .foregroundColor(showSecondView == true ? .green : .black)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        
        .padding(.leading)
    }
    var editButton : some View {
        Button {
            
        } label: {
            Text("Edit")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don’t use form use a Vstack and make it your own.

Comment: @loremipsum But this way there's still all the top space from the navigation bar of the Navigation View